# How to disable concurrent gc for C# class library

Tags: garbage-collection

I have found answers to disable concurrent garbage collection for an application that uses config file. But my C# app is a class library built for ArcGIS, and don't have a config file.

How to disable the concurrent gc in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The decision over which GC flavor to use is up to the application (host) and not external DLLs.